# Convergence of infinite series from 2 to infinity 1/(x((lnx)^2))

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

On a recent exam I was asked to test the following series for convergence

From $2$ to $\infty$

$\frac{1}{x(lnx)^{2}}$

I blanked on the integral but set up a comparison test, saying that $\frac{1}{x(\ln x)^{2}}$ < $\frac{1}{(\ln x)^{2}}$ for all $x$. I then substituted $\ln x =t$, so $x=e^{t}$ and rewrote the comparison as $\frac{1}{e^{t}t^{2}} $< $\frac{1}{t^{2}}$ for all $t$, and concluded that the series is convergent because it is less than the p-series with $p=2$. This makes sense to me, and graphically it seems to make sense if you plot all four functions, but my professor isn't sure if it is a legal operation to make a substitution and use the comparison. I am looking for a more rigorous way to justify this, or perhaps a clear explanation of where I went wrong.

Sorry in advance for the formatting, this was posted from my tablet, and I don't know exactly how to enter formulas with that.

Comment: The integral test by @science is the correct idea to do it. Just want to remark that your substitution won't work because that will make the limit $t=\ln{2}, \ln{3}, ...$ which cannot compare with the p-series.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can use the [integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) by studying the integral

$$ \int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z\ln^2(z)}dz. $$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_x 1/(\ln x)^2$ is not a convergent series, so your proof doesn't work. One way to approach the problem is to use the Cauchy condensation test: Since the terms in your series are positive decreasing, your series $\sum_x a_x$ converges if and only if $\sum_k 2^k a_{2^k}$ converges. That second series leads you to a series proportional to $\sum_k 1/k^2$ which is convergent.